# Disable auto scrolling while moving to other pages in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, scroll

I have developed a single page application in angularJS where all the pages will contain scrolling so when I scroll to bottom in first page it is applying to the remaining pages also. So all i want is how to get the remaining pages not scroll according to the previous page.?

Please any help regarding this problem
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the autoscroll-argument of the [ng-view](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) directive, which is calling $anchorScroll.

Comment: sorry i have checked that it is not helping

Comment: Dude, you got to provide us with more information here. E.g. why that is not helpful. What exactly is your problem looking like. What "paging"-mechanism are you using?

Comment: Well its not paging its just two pages with scrolling when one page is scrolled to the bottom. and I moved to the second page, now the second page is also scrolled to bottom.

I said it is not helpful means that i have tried that mechanism but the results are same that's why I said it is not helpful

Comment: This is not a default behaviour. Did you test this on several browsers?
With "paging"-mechanism i meant: Do you use ui-router or ngRoute for switching between pages?

Comment: no I am not using ui-router or ng-router for navigation i use "location"  to navigate and this is a android mobile app even though i have tested in several devices but it is showing the same behavior

Comment: in this case try to test it in e.g. chrome. If it shouldn't work there either, pls provide us with a code example (plnkr)

Comment: it is working while i am using it in chrome but not in mobile devices and more over i got an work around for that by using '$anchorScroll'